# Kendo Grid select event

Tags: kendo-grid

After upgrading Kendo to 2014.3.1119, following code which was giving me Grid header select event, is no longer working.

```
   $('#kendoGridId').live("focus", function() {
       inFocus = true;
   });
```

Where

```
$("#kendoGridId").kendoGrid( .... );
```

With new Kendo, I tried

```
$('#kendoGridId').bind("focus", function(),
```

but it's not working. Is there any API which I can use to get this Kendo Grid Header select event back ?

Answer (score 1):

plz try this for bind event on Kendo Grid Header...

```
$("#grid").find(".k-header").on("click",function(){alert("clicked");})
```

if you like this than don't forget to vote me..

Comment: Hi..you just write above code in dataBound event of Grid..so every time it's get bind with Grid when you refresh the grid.